# Geometry table for use in regexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

I have been teaching myself Python 3. I watched a video on YouTube entitled "stop writing classes". The Gtable class doesn't even have an init function, so I can't help but wonder if I should have done something different. Also as someone teaching themselves a language for the first time I would really appreciate any critique on how to write the code more efficiently, as well as any anti-idioms unintentionally used. Specifically I feel like there was probably a better way to generate the dictionaries, but especially with the first one I was having trouble writing a comprehension.

```
##input file text
##|HAAS T|TARGET T|XGEOM|ZGEOM
##$T0101$T0101$X22.960$Z20.0$
##$T0202$T0606$X32.425$Z7.376$
##$T0303$T0404$X30.588$Z15.620$
##$T0404$T0202$X22.367$Z18.549$
##$T0505$T0808$X33.291$Z8.197$

class GeometryTable(dict):
    "create a geometry table from a file for use in regexes"
    def __init__(self):
        self.d={}
    def create(self,location):
        f=open(location,'r')
        tablestring=f.read()
        f.close()
        tablelist=[]
        tablelist=tablestring.split('$')
        #delete unecessary data from list
        tablelist.pop(0)
        tablelist=[item for item in tablelist if item!='\n']
        #create a dictionary
        count=0
        keylist=[]
        valuelist=[]
        while count<len(tablelist):
            keylist.append(tablelist[count])
            valuelist.append([tablelist[count+1],tablelist[count+2],tablelist[count+3]])
            count+=4
        self.d=dict(zip(keylist,valuelist))
    def xval(self,string):
        if string in self.d:
            return (self.d[string][1])
        else:return(r"X20.0")
    def zval(self,string):
        if string in self.d:
            return (self.d[string][2])
        else:return(r"Z20.0")
    def tval(self,string):
        if string in self.d:
            return (self.d[string][0])
        else:return(r"T2020")
    def report(self,string):
        if string in self.d:
            return (self.d[string])
        else:return(r"(no value)")


class GTable(GeometryTable):
    """for replacing geometries that were given
       default values before this program was created"""
    def load(self,location):
        GeometryTable.load(self,location)
        b=self.__dict__["d"].values()
        redict={x[0]:x for x in b}
        self.d=redict

##output dictionaries for regular expressions
##>>> test.d
##{'T0101': ['T0101', 'X22.960', 'Z20.0'],
## 'T0202': ['T0606', 'X32.425', 'Z7.376'],
## 'T0303': ['T0404', 'X30.588', 'Z15.620'],
## 'T0404': ['T0202', 'X22.367', 'Z18.549'],
## 'T0505': ['T0808', 'X33.291', 'Z8.197']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Misnomer

`GeometryTable.create()` is poorly named: it doesn't *create* a `GeometryTable`.  Rather, it *loads* tabular geometry data from a file.  Therefore, it should be called `load()` instead.  With that simple renaming, the following code starts to make sense:

```
table = GeometryTable()
table.load('part1.dat')    # Loads some data
table.load('part2.dat')    # Loads more data into the same object
```

#### Inappropriate inheritance, Part I

`GeometryTable` inherits from `dict`.  Why?  Would you say that `GeometryTable` *is* a `dict`, or that `GeometryTable` *uses* a `dict`?  The latter is clearly true: it uses a `dict` called `self.d`.  The former isn't true: you couldn't meaningfully write code like

```
table = GeometryTable()
table.load('something.dat')
table['T0202']             # ← Produces a KeyError
```

Therefore, as you've designed it, `GeometryTable` should just be an `object`, not a `dict`.

That said, you could change `GeometryTable` so that it *is* a `dict`, such that you can call `table['T0202'].x`.  I don't really recommend doing so.  "Prefer composition over inheritance" is a [general](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/134097/51698) [maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/1157100) of object-oriented design.

#### Meaningless array indices

Expressions like `tablelist[count+2]` and `self.d[string][1]` are mysterious and hard to understand.  I recommend the use of [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) so that you can have meaningful names like `self.d[string].x` instead.

#### Too much code

You're working too hard.  `load()` could be written in five lines.  Furthermore, for readability, efficiency, and scalability, it's better to work line by line rather than reading the entire file at once.

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

class GeometryTable(object):
    Row = namedtuple('Row', ['t', 'x', 'z'])
    default_row = lambda cls: cls.Row('T2020', 'X20.0', 'Z20.0')

    def __init__(self):
        self.d = defaultdict(self.default_row)

    def load(self, filename):
        """
        Loads data in the following format from the named file:

            |HAAS T|TARGET T|XGEOM|ZGEOM
            $T0101$T0101$X22.960$Z20.0$
            $T0202$T0606$X32.425$Z7.376$
            $T0303$T0404$X30.588$Z15.620$
            $T0404$T0202$X22.367$Z18.549$
            $T0505$T0808$X33.291$Z8.197$
        """
        with open(filename) as f:
            next(f)     # Discard first line, which contains a header
            for line in f:
                cols = line.split('$')
                self.d[cols[1]] = self.Row(*cols[2:5])

    def tval(self, haas):
        return self.d[haas].t

    def xval(self, haas):
        return self.d[haas].x

    def zval(self, haas):
        return self.d[haas].z

    def report(self, haas):
        return self.d.get(haas, '(no value)')
```

Alternatively, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

class GeometryTable(object):
    …
    def load(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            next(f)     # Discard first line, which contains a header
            rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter='$')
            for cols in rows:
                self.d[cols[1]] = self.Row(*cols[2:5])
```

One minor deviation from your original code is that `.report()` returns a `namedtuple` rather than a list.  However, considering that it sometimes returns a string instead (which is weird), I assume that that is an inconsequential detail.

#### Inappropriate inheritance, Part II

Your `GTable` class doesn't actually work.  For one thing, `Geometrytable` is mis-capitalized, so it's evidently untested code.

The call to `Geometrytable.create(self,location)` would be better written as `super().load(filename)` (with the renaming suggested earlier).

Instead of `self.__dict__["d"]`, why not just write `self.d`?

The biggest problem, though, is that a `GTable` simply isn't a `GeometryTable`.  The methods `.tval()`, `.xval()`, and `.zval()` will all give wrong results, since their implementation is simply incompatible `GTable`'s data representation.  I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with `GTable`, but inheritance is not the right solution.

Comment: Namedtuple feature as well as the use of defaults. This was very informative and helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So there are a few improvements that I can see in your code, mainly in the `create` function.

---

When reading a file, use the `with` keyword. This will open the file and, once the program leaves that scope, the file will automatically be closed.

I would recommend changing how you read the file. From what I can tell, each line will be its own key in your `dict`. So instead of reading the **entire** file in one statement, I would recommend reading line-by-line.

By making the changes mentioned above, when we split the input by `$`, we get unnecessary values in the first and last index of the resulting `list`. To fix this, we can use [list slicing](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/2017002/python-101-unit-1-understanding-indices-and-slicing). By using the notation `list[start:end]`, where `start` specifies the first index you want **included** and `stop` specifies the first index you want **excluded**, we can remove the first and last indices.

Finally, when creating a `dict` you can assign a key-value pair simply by using the syntax:

```
dict[key] = value
```

Bringing all of these suggestions together, here is my version of your `create` function:

```
def create(self, location):
    # Once this block of code finishes, f will close.
    with open(location, 'r') as f:
        # Reads the file line-by-line
        for line in f:
            # Split the data and remove the first and last indices
            data = line.split('$')[1:-1]

            # Assign the key-value pair to the dict
            self.d[data[0]] = data[1:]
```

---

As a final aside, look over [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). PEP8 is the official Python style guide. Following those conventions (especially underscores in variable names, so `table_string` instead of `tablestring`) will help your code look and feel more Pythonic.

Comment: That worked really well with one small tweak. Added:                if len(data)>1:self.d[data[0]] = data[1:] to handle index out of range error. Thankyou